# Redemption API not working when service Id is logged off

Tags: c#, .net, outlook-2010, outlook-redemption

I use the below code to connect to an outlook profile configured in the local server.

```
RdsObj = new RDOSession();                
RdsObj.Logon(Common.EMAILPROFILENAME, "", false, true, 0, false);                
InBoxFolder = RdsObj.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

The profile is configured to connect to an outlook 2010 exchange server, (in future this exchange server can get migrated to newer versions). The code is running on a Windows Service running every few seconds and is running under a service id account that has all privileges to access the local Outlook profile. It works fine as long as the Windows Service id is logged on that server & the Logon session is active but as soon as the Windows Service id is logged off from the server, i get the below error message.

"Message : Error in MAPILogonEx: MAPI_E_LOGON_FAILED
Make sure your code runs under the Windows user identity that has MAPI profiles.
When running in a service (including ASP under IIS), set your code to run under
the Windows user account that has MAPI profiles.
When connecting to an Exchange Server, you can also use RDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox
which does not require an existing profile.
Source : Redemption.RDOSession
"

The service id account will be automatically logged off due to company policy every few days and is causing concerns. How do i fix this issue?

Comment: Is running the service under the Windows account of the user who has the profile configured an option?

Comment: Yes it is running like that. The service is running under the Windows Account of the user who has the Outlook profile configured.

Comment: I am confused - do you mean the service account is getting logged off? if that is the case, MSEMS MAPI provider cannot use the identity of the parent process to authenticate with the server. Can you terminate the service in case of this exception to force the service manager to restart the service?

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, somehow the issue got resolved, after a server restart. Now the error message do not appear even if the Windows session is logged off.